# Applications of Grover's algorithm in machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, quantum-computing

I am trying to see applications of grover's algorithm. I have seen it can be applied in the DNA sequence alignment. I was wondering where in machine learning (deep learning, NLP and reinforcement learning) can i use the grover's algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Grover-augmented [Viterbi algorithm](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/2007/2007.10328.pdf) with a claimed quadratic runtime speedup. Methods have also been proposed for [Quantum Reinforcement Learning](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0810.3828.pdf). More relevant than the search algorithm itself is the iterative process used to rotate the state vector, which has applications in algorithms in a number of domains (most prominently these days in quantum cryptography).